# Attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I was trying to change some function of this project [Media player](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/) to read mp3 from raw folder and not from SD card.  but it throws me an error "Attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer" please any advice ?

```
 public void  playSong(int songIndex){ // parameter is not used. is set static content

    try {
        mp.reset();
        mp = mp.create(this, R.raw.ledzepellin); // static content!
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();

        String songTitle = "title";
        songTitleLabel.setText(songTitle);


        songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
        songProgressBar.setMax(100);


        updateProgressBar();

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void updateProgressBar() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
}


private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        long totalDuration = mp.getDuration(); // ---- HERE IT GIVE ME ERROR
        long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();


        songTotalDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));

        songCurrentDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));


        int progress = (int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));

        songProgressBar.setProgress(progress);


        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};
```

here i start playSong method it first it open me a listview of available songs when i choose ti give me back result in extras but its not important raw source is set staticly

```
       btnPlaylist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayListActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 100);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == 100){
        currentSongIndex = data.getExtras().getInt("songIndex");

        playSong(currentSongIndex);
    }

}
```

Comment: Where do you run `playSong` method?

Comment: @Yurdaaaaa, I am facing same problem please tell me how you solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for the static `create` method you are calling says:

> On success, prepare() will already have been called and must not be called again.

Are there not other errors being printed to logcat? You might consider adding an error listener using `setOnErrorListener`, and also taking a look at the state diagram [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html). Most methods should not be called while the `MediaPlayer` is idle or in an error state. In your case, I believe it has gone into an error state after `prepare()` and should be causing problems from then on.

Comment: thanks you i little bit change the code and functions and now is code little bit buggy but working :)

Comment: hello @Yurdaaaaa i got same error what change you do in function please help me.